# Routing issue Error: No component factory found with Angular 7

Tags: angular

thanks for reading. I am trying to lazy load modules with Angular 7 but I am running into an error which I cannot see where I'm doing this incorrectly.

Here's my structure:

`/app/routes/app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home/home.component';
import { RegisterContainerModule } from '../modules/register-container.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterContainerModule
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The `homeComponent` route routes fine, it's when I try to route to `register` that I get the issue:

`/app/modules/register-container.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RegisterComponent } from '../pages/register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [RegisterComponent]
})
export class RegisterContainerModule { }
```

The `registerComponent` is default created from `ng generate component register` and placed in `/app/pages/register/` and just says "register works". No other work has been done to it.

My main `app-module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './routes/app-routing.module';
import { RegisterContainerModule } from './modules/register-container.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './pages/register/register.component';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RegisterContainerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lazy loading documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) covers a different approach than you are taking.  It has very good coverage of the feature and is recommended reading.

The following shows how to do it in your case:

You can't have code references to the modules you are going to lazy load.    If you do then that code ends up in the wrong bundle.   So you have to use a string reference.

First off you don't want to register the component in the `app-module.ts` 
So remove `entryComponents` items and the `import`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './routes/app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Change: `/app/routes/app-routing.module.ts` to:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: '../modules/register-container.module#RegisterContainerModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then you need a routing module `routes/register-container-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../pages/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegisterComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegisterContainerRoutingModule {}
```

Finally, in your RegisterContainerModule, you will need to import the new RoutingModule.   You also don't need the entryComponents section.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RegisterComponent } from '../pages/register/register.component';
import { RegisterContainerRoutingModule } from '../routes/register-continer-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RegisterContainerRoutingModule
  ]
})

export class RegisterContainerModule { }
```

Comment: This results in `NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/register', error: TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function)`

Comment: @thatgibbyguy does this occur at runtime or compile time?   If at runtime are you visiting the URL directly or via a link on the Home Component?

Comment: Runtime, I'm getting that error in my browser's console. I'm getting to the route via `routerLink="register"` from the `homeComponent`.

Comment: Also, just tried going directly to the route and getting the same issue. This is after a completely new `ng serve`

Comment: Of note, I use firefox to dev in, but if I go to Chrome I get a different error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: I have a working copy of this on my machine now, I edited the answer to include each file.

Answer (score 0):

In your **AppRoutingModule** modify the route for *register* like this

```
{
path: 'register',
loadChildren: '../modules/registercontainer.module#RegisterContainerModule'
}
```

The **loadChildren** will do lazy loading for **RegisterContainerModule**.

Now once you have lazy loaded RegisterContainerModule, you'll have to create routes (child routes) for this module. Like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from './pages/register/register.component';
const childRoutes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: RegisterComponent
}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegisterModuleRoute{ }
```

See in the routes of Lazy Loaded Module, we are registering routes with **forChild** method.

More changes you require in your code

1.) You don't need to give a bootstrap component bootstrap: [RegisterComponent] in the **RegisterContainerModule**

2.) **RegisterComponent** shall be declared in the **RegisterContainerModule** only and not in the AppModule.

Thanx

Comment: I have been under the impression that this is not lazy loading as code can't be separated into other bundles.     RegisterContainerModule needs to be a string reference see my answer.

Comment: I tried this method, but I now get `Component RegisterComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Comment: RegisterComponent component must be declared in the module its part of. So make sure its part of the declarations array of the RegisterContainerModule. If its needed in other modules too, then also add it in the exports:[] array of RegisterContainerModule.